# How to run DotNetOpenAuth Demo?

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

who can tell me,How to run DotNetOpenAuth Demo?
this demo:
Interop with Authorization Server sample (Authorization code grant) and Resource Server using WCF w/ OAuth 2.0

when I run this demo,key wroing openid,it will show Serialize contains no elements.

```
var request = rp.CreateRequest(model.UserSuppliedIdentifier, 
          Realm.AutoDetect,
          new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Action("Authenticate"))
);
```

error on this line.
who can tell me why?

Comment: Did you use your own keys in the config?

Comment: No.I use the default configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set up the keys for the webservice you are trying to authorize against.
It's probably the default values which aren't valid for making a request.